# How to format a variable of double type

Tags: java, formatting

I have a variable of double type representing a value of about 34.323423423123456. I'd like to format it to have only two decimal places (e.g. 34.32), rounded properly; e.g. 2.229934345 would become 2.23.

I am new to Java and none the tricks I know from C# worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) use DecimalFormat [setRoundingMode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example format string, I believe it correctly rounds the resulting value.  See Markus' post if you need more control over the rounding or format:

```
String.format("%.2f", 2.229934345);
```